# send&receive sms messages from Ubuntu, using a built-in sim slot + sim card

Tags: mobile-broadband, sms

I have a laptop on which I run Ubuntu 18.04, the laptop has a built-in sim slot and I have a sim card that I use for mobile broadband.

Is there any software that I can use to send and receive sms messages, using the sim card that I also use for internet?

Comment: Mobile Broadband devices typically can't send SMS messages, they're designed to only use data.  I have several systems with Mobile Broadband cards, but they don't have SMS capability in the mobile broadband card/firmware/software to *do* SMS messages.

Comment: `ofono` would be the necessary back-end piece to send/receive SMS. However, as already mentioned if your SIM is a data-only card, you won't be able to, not having a phone number assigned to it.

Comment: it is not a data card only, I have a number on it + a voice and sms plan activated :) thanks.

Comment: found it! Modem Manager GUI - works like a charm!

Comment: @Alexandra Would you post whatever solution you have found as a detailed answer? It will be helpful for other users

Comment: hi :) yes, sure. I have installed a software called 'Modem Manager GUI' and this has - out of the box - the functionality I was looking for. I have just configured my mobile broadband, and after that, once you install the software it will just recognize the broadband connection. from within the software interface I can send and receive sms massages, it has a USSD functionality (I wasn't able to have this working, so far) and I can also see a traffic statistic that looks pretty nice.

Comment: this is the software https://linuxonly.ru/page/modem-manager-gui, I have used 'Ubuntu Software' to install it.

Answer (score 2):

As Alexandra mentioned, Modem Manager GUI worked perfectly with my usb 3G dongle. Supported SMS and USSD which made it a great tool to manage this sim. Like the fact that any new SMS messages pops up in my notification panel. 
Easy install from command line as well. sudo apt-get install modem-manager-gui

Comment: It work but I have not found a tool that does it from command line and I expect to run script server side to send sms. Is there another option,  mmcli fail to help